# Pax exam 2: gave up waiting for service

Tags: java, osgi, apache-karaf, pax-exam

I'm trying to make some pax-exam-karaf tests with many bundles (cxf-jaxrs, aries-tx, jpa...).
Tests are working great on my local environment (a strong i7 computer), but fails on my C.I server:
Caused by: org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.framework.ServiceLookupException: gave up waiting for service

The error is pretty explicit: I reached the timeout of pax-exam, and the question is: how can I configure this timeout?

I tried setting systemTimeout(5000000) option, but it seems not to be taken in account.

Is it a karaf configuration issue or a pax one?

The other question is about the release of exam 3.1.0 that supports Karaf feature: I'm a geek and want to be at the top of the technology!

Best regards and one more time thanks for this wonder-useful framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the @Filter annotation with its timeout attribute. See [Dependency Injection](https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/paxexam/Dependency+Injection).

Comment: Yes! I switched to pax-exam 3 and used @Filter annotation. Thank you!